# Instance class or method without an interface?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

## Got this code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface CalculatorBrain : NSObject
- (void)pushOperand:(double)operand;
- (double)performOperation:(NSString *)op;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) id program;
+ (NSString *)descriptionOfProgram:(id)program;
+ (double)runProgram:(id)program;
@end
```

## And this one:

```
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"
@interface CalculatorBrain()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *programStack;
@end
@implementation CalculatorBrain
@synthesize programStack = _programStack;
- (NSMutableArray *)programStack
{
if (_programStack == nil) _programStack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
return _programStack;
}
- (id)program
{
return [self.programStack copy];
}
+ (NSString *)descriptionOfProgram:(id)program
{
return @"blablabla";
}
    - (void)pushOperand:(double)operand
{
   [self.programStack addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:operand]];
}

- (double)performOperation:(NSString *)operation
{
[self.programStack addObject:operation];
return [[self class] runProgram:self.program];
}

+ (double)popOperandOffProgramStack:(NSMutableArray *)stack
{
   double result = 0;
   return result;
}
+ (double)runProgram:(id)program
{
   NSMutableArray *stack;
   if ([program isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
      stack = [program mutableCopy];
   }
   return [self popOperandOffProgramStack:stack];
}
@end
```

The code is fine an it runs, so the question is, Where is declared **popOperandOffProgramStack** in the interface? why it compiles and it's okay? it should crash but I can not find an explanation to this....

Thank you!

Comment: 'it should crash' - why should it? The method is implemented... (got it? One of the most wonderful properties of Objective-C is that it's *dynamic*...)

Comment: thank you, just realized about that, it's pretty cool, I'm coming from Java, it's a little big different but with your support I'm leaving newbie area soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to declare methods in the `@interface` in the .h file if you're exposing them to the world. Otherwise, no declaration needed.

And nowadays, the order that they appear in the implementation doesn't matter, either. Historically, if the method was implemented later in the `@implementation` than where it was invoked, you needed to have the method declared above (generally in the `@interface`). Now the compiler doesn't care whether the implementation is earlier or later in the .m file.

Answer (score 2):

the compiler can sees its definition:

```
+ (double)popOperandOffProgramStack:(NSMutableArray *)stack
{
   double result = 0;
   return result;
}
```

so it is able to confirm it has been declared, the parameter types, and return type.

also - in older compilers, it would need to precede usage, but not anymore if used in the `@implementation` scope.

even if it were not declared, objc is weak enough that it would not be a compiler error (warning, perhaps). exception: the method must be visible if you're using ARC. the compiler needs to know the reference counting semantics and parameter types when ARC is enabled.

Comment: (Somewhat unfortunately) it _is_ now an error if you're compiling with ARC.

Comment: @W'rkncacnter thanks - added. forgot because i rarely use ARC.